# numbers changing to date in excel, workaround causes #VALUE

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv, dbeaver

This is the original database

```
repaid to_repay 
436,86   805
96,25    990
1,5    2.200
```

When I export the DBeaver sql query to clipboard and then paste it to MS Excel,
the last row repaid changes to:

```
repaid    to_repay
436.86    805.00
96.25     990.00
Jan 50   2200.00
```

I read that the workaround is to pre-set the columns to the format "text".
When I did that, the numbers are correct. Then, I changed the format to "number" and used those cells as a reference to another cell, but the result of that is `#VALUE!` even though the formula is correct.

If I pre-set the columns to the format "number",
the result is:

```
repaid    to_repay
436.86    805.00
96.25     990.00
18264,00   2200.00
```

So how can I get my excel to produce the output as in my sql database, and it won't produce #VALUE! when the cells are used as reference for other cells?

Comment: i don't see any options how to do that.. i copy pasted the result

Comment: i changed the default macos decimal separator, but the problem persists

Comment: You can use "export" functionality and csv as output format. Here you can disable number formatting. Or use "open with -> web browser" and copy data from there.

Comment: i am not sure how to do that ? @astentx

Comment: Have you tried using dots instead of commas? Select all the data (Ctrl + A), then press Ctrl + H. In the first field write in a comma, in the 2nd field write in a dot. Press replace all.

Comment: @Luc Just click on your results grid and explore the menu, there should be "export"